# Java SimpleDateFormat parsing

Tags: java, android, parsing, simpledateformat

Trying to parse date as follows:

```
String startDate = "Tue May 15 00:00:01 MSK 2012";
SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
Date date = (Date) parser .parse(startDate );
String formattedDate = parser .format(date );
```

and I get this error:

> 08-15 11:18:22.005: W/System.err(1012): java.text.ParseException:
>   Unparseable date: "Tue May 15 00:00:01 MSK 2012" 08-15 11:18:22.045:
>   W/System.err(1012):   at
>   java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:626)

How can I resolve it?

Comment: I solve my problem whit this
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");

Answer (score 2):

`SimpleDateFormat` by default uses the default locale: the given code will work when run on a system configured for English and fail elsewhere. You can set the locale to a known one when creating the parser, for example:

```
String startDate = "Tue May 15 00:00:01 MSK 2012";
SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.US);
Date date = (Date) parser .parse(startDate );
String formattedDate = parser .format(date );
```